# Nodemon aequivalent to npm run dev

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I've just started using the whole javascript and node.js environment. To start an existing project I run three commands 
`npm install`, `npm run all` and finally `npm run dev` to start the application in my browser.

Now, whenever I update the code I stop the current running dev via `Ctrl+C`, press arrow up key to get `npm run dev` in my terminal again and hit `Enter`. I believe there is a better way of doing this repetitive task, like [Nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon).

But, what is the aequivalent command for that, so that the updates I make in the code automatically become visible in the browser?

I have three files which do not work with nodeman: `package.json`, `Gruntfile.js`, `app/index.js`. Moreover, I tried `nodemon --exec npm run dev` which permanently does sth, but does not start my application.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: To have changes you make in your code automatically reflected in the browser, you normally use something like webpack. nodemon is more useful when you are working on a server-side script.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would look at the `--exec` flag on `nodemon`. You could do something like:

```
nodemon --exec npm run dev
```

This will run `npm run dev` every time a source file changes. Read the [nodemon NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#running-non-node-scripts) to get a better idea of how to use it.